# GWT RichTextArea get expand on Chome/Safari iOS

Tags: java, ios, css, gwt, richtextbox

I have RichTextArea in a Absolute panel.

When user enter text without return (new line) text area grows horizontally beyond panel size.
Same is true if user keeps entering return text area grows vertically beyond panel size.

Please let me know how I can solve this. On other browsers it works. If text exceeds it come to next line or scroll appears.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width and height attribute of the text area should do the trick. It's working fine on my Chrome browser.